# I have WebSphere webservices consumer and webservices provider on same machine, how can I configure it to use the local interface?

Tags: networking, deployment, websphere, administration

I have the Service consumer and services provider on the same machine.   The service consumer sends a large chunk of data to the service provider.

Can the web service provider be configured to accept this large payload through a 'local' interface, instead of relaying on the underlying network to carry the packets?  I'm looking for the most efficient way to transfer this large data set from the producer to the consumer on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

If it's traditional WebSphere, not Liberty, check out in-process connections, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rrun_inbound.html .  That's for same process, not just same machine.

Comment: Bruce - thank you.   I'm guessing that this does NOT apply to a Java application that's running on the same host as the WebSphere. If I understand it correctly, they have to run in the same container (JVM).

Comment: Since webservices are intended to use http, if it's two different processes, it will go over the network, but if the host machine is configured correctly (as far as knowing it's own hostname) then it should not leave the machine.

Traditional WebSphere also supports web services using JMS, if you're adventurous.